# IE9, copy a table to a TextEditor like notepad, the table structure is lost

Tags: html-table, copy, internet-explorer-9, paste

A very simple case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Render the page in IE9, copy the table out, paste into a text editor like NotePad, you will find that the output is

```
1
2
3
4
```

That is not good, I tested in Firefox and other browsers, they can render 1 & 2 (3 & 4) into one row.

Also it looks like if I change IE9 to QuirksMode, it will work well.

How can I make the table copied correctly in IE9 standard mode, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has issues with whitespace when it comes to tables...

Try:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: here is my source... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/28d78780-c95c-4c35-9695-237ebb912d90

Comment: I do not understand... what the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can keep your original doctype choice while [adding](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype) an `X-UA-Compatible` *HTTP header* or *meta tag* (which is invalid in HTML5) on your page.

I.e. this seems to fix your copy/paste issue in IE9, while still triggering the standards [mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) in other browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<body>
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```